# Unable to copy file exception in TFS build

Tags: visual-studio-2010, msbuild, teamcity

I am getting following error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets (178): Unable to copy file "bin\AjaxControlToolkit.pdb" to "C:\Builds\2\testbox\test\Binaries\_PublishedWebsites\test\bin\AjaxControlToolkit.pdb". Could not find a part of the path 'bin\AjaxControlToolkit.pdb'.
```

Just checked file is available on path.
same working fine on local as well as while building from team city. Don't know whats going wrong.

Edited

Just cant understand why it is trying to copy from obj directory..Please see the following log

```
 Copying file from "obj\Debug\Manager.dll" to "C:\Builds\2\box\Two\Binaries\Manager.dll".
Manager -> C:\Builds\2\box\Two\Binaries\Manager.dll
Copying file from "obj\Debug\Manager.pdb" to "C:\Builds\2\box\Two\Binaries\Manager.pdb".
Copying file from "obj\Debug\Manager.xml" to "C:\Builds\2\box\Two\Binaries\Manager.xml".
Done Building Project "C:\Builds\2\box\Two\Sources\Manager\Manager.vbproj" (default targets)
```

Where as I have set the output to bin.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reasons:

1. This reference is dynamic, meaning its path gets cleared and created on each build. Third party reference files should be checked in the source control to a common shared folder (e.g. `\lib`).
2. Your project have a file reference to AjaxControlToolkit to a path
   which does not exist on build the server. Open the project's `.csproj`
   file,and check the `HintPath` of *AjaxControlToolkit*.
3. Avoid referencing third party assemblies from the GAC (where the first bullet is applicable).

Comment: Plz see the edit section...as tried all what you said but couldnt fix it.

Comment: I think problem was with build agent working directory. I deleted the current working directory and changed the working directory to a different path and all builds starting to pass.